# dynamic series and points for highchart go to wrong point

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, highcharts

In my quest in creating dynamic charts that don't rely on any manually entered series or data for the series I've ran into a hiccup. I'm adding the correct amount of series and the correct  data but it happens to be in incorrect series or x-axis point. Some of the points are off by 1 and I believe I've isolated where it's messing up but cannot see it.

```
        function chartCreate(point) {
        var temp;
        temp = $.parseJSON(point.d);
        $.each(temp, function (key, p) {
            var seriesObj;

            seriesObj = seriesExists(p.mcAnswer);
            if (seriesObj.status == 'f') {
                var name = p.mcAnswer.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
                //var name = p.mcAnswer.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
                chart1.addSeries({ name: name, data: [] }, false);
                chart1.series[seriesObj.count].addPoint(p.total, false);
            } else {
                chart1.series[seriesObj.count].addPoint(p.total, false);
            }
        });
    };

    //loops through all the series to see if the series exists.
    //if true returns index and true if not just returns false
    function seriesExists(name) {
        name = name.trim();
        var ct = 0;
        var returnObj = { count: ct, status: 'f' };
        var len = chart1.series.length;
        //            var len = 0;
        if (len > 0) {
            $.each(chart1.series, function (count, curSeries) {
                ct = count;
                var temp = curSeries.name;
                temp = temp.trim();
                if (temp == name) {
                    returnObj = { count: ct, status: 't' };
                    return (false);
                } else {
                    returnObj = { count: ct, status: 'f' };
                }
                //ct = count;
            });
        }
        return returnObj;
    };
```

I believe the error occurs in the .each of the seriesExists function. for the json that is passed to this everything was made to be in order making it so as you go through each object in the loop it would be in order when adding the points. the odd thing that occurs is not all of the points added are in the wrong spot and only one of them is in the wrong series.
[image: this appears when trying to export]
saving of incorrect chart

[image: what incorrect chart actually looks like on screen]
incorrect chart just a few off

[image: correct chart]
correct chart

Comment: Can you generate sample fiddle with the data that is creating problem ?

Comment: I updated with screenshots, there's ajax calls and everything in the background to grab the data

Comment: It is really hard to tell what is going on here since we do not know the position of the correct elements and each chart is different (not going to OCR your image). Can you put up a basic jsFiddle using dynamic data looping? Just use a hardcoded var that acts like your JSON.

Comment: Could you paste your JSON ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it took so long I was pulled into another project. I was able to create correct charts by going through each object and storing those in a temp array. After I went through all the objects from the ajax call I would then use addSeries and it would correctly create the chart.